# How should I finish a shower stall at an outside corner?

Tags: drywall, shower

I'm replacing a shower stall in an alcove with a plastic modular unit. The old unit ended a few inches inside the stall, while the new unit extends right to the edge of the alcove.  On one corner, the shower surround flange is nearly touching (the back of) the drywall on the other wall. 
The surround flange itself is about 1 3/8". There's also about 2" high of exposed stud at the bottom where the shower pan is.

[image]

How should I fill in the space on the surround at this corner?  I was considering either trying to fit in a small strip of drywall, or filling it in with setting-type compound. I'd then put plastic corner bead on top. I might need to pre-drill some holes in the surround flange in order to attach the bead.

Comment: A picture is worth at least a few more words than you provided. It's not clear what your layout is or where the problem lies.

Comment: You may be too new to insert a picture. Post it on imgur.com and stick the link to it in a comment. One of us will insert it into your question for you.

Comment: Are you looking for material suggestions or technical suggestions for how to do the corners for instance? Are you putting a shower door on this?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution - overlap the shower flange where you can, and fill the gaps with Durabond.

Complex solution - rip that little strip of drywall off, overlap with a larger piece, that wraps around the top of the shower.

In both cases, you'll want to put "corner bead", on the corner pictured, that goes from floor to ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, in almost any modular shower install, furring strips are applied to the framing to bring it out flush with the shower flange, and drywall is installed in the usual fashion, lapping over the flange. Corner bead is applied to the outside corner, and taping commences as normal. When taping is complete you may want to caulk against the shower. I see no reason to deviate from that plan here.